# In bootstrap, what is the meaning of article.col-sm-10 in a style tag?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm studying BootStrap, and I don't understand the behavior of this piece of code:

```
 <style type="text/css">
  article.col-sm-10, nav.col-sm-2 {
    line-height: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

Does it mean that articles, `col-sm-10`, `nav` and `col-sm-2` will be affected by a `line-height` of `10 px`, or is it for `articles` **with** `col-sm-10` and `nv` **with** `col-sm-2` attributs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It means the following elements will have a 10px line height:

```
<article class="col-sm-10">
  ...
</article>

<nav class="col-sm-2">
  ...
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

articles with col-sm-10 and nv with col-sm-2 will have line- height of 10

Answer (score 0):

article.col-sm-10 is a breadcrumb class in css